# ¿Cómo añadir los textbox y componentes de una forma si no me aparecen en el cuadro de herramientas?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

verán, no me sale ningún componente para agregar a la forma que cree en c# y no sé qué hacer o por qué no me sale... ¿Tengo que instalar algo especial para que me salgan?, estoy usando visual studio community... ¿Es por eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es raro.. no sale ningun error por ningun lado.. ni en el log ni en ningun lado? que pasa si traes un proyecto ya creado que los tenga?

Comment: No me sale ningún error ni nada, si tengo un proyecto ya creado me sale lo mismo, sólo al crear otra forma me vuelven a salir los controles en el cuadro de herramientas, pero al volver a entrar al proyecto vuelven a desaparecer.